# Access Database field query

Tags: ms-access

I am currently making a very simply database but haven't made one in a while.
My issue is that I have one table, Drinks, which has a column (the technical terms slips my mind) that is called ingredients. This column will be populated from two other tables, volume and ingred.  I have split these tables up because there are many drinks that use the same ingredients but different volumes of them. So my question is what kind of query/relationship should I have to get the column to be correctly populated.

[image: Relationships in the table]

[image: Drinks Table]

Comment: Cannot have one field populated with values from 2 tables. You need another table (a dependent 'child' table) to document the 'recipe' (ingredients and quantities) for each drink. You should review an introductory tutorial on relational database concepts and Access functionality. You are using multi-value fields for Technique and Garnish. I have never used and do not recommend multi-value fields but might be satisfactory in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your main table (Drinks)  you need reference  to  splitted table. For example instead of ingredients field  you need  ingredients_id and the same for other splitted tables.

Then you  can use  one to many  query  to populate  your data  as you  wish.